# Transferring ec2 instances between accounts

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm writing an app for a client on a ec2 instance, and now it's time to setup a prod ec2 instance under his AWS account. Can I somehow transfer the ec2 instance which is running under my account to his account? Or I would have to create prod environment from scratch?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Create an AMI of that instance and share the AMI with the other account.  Take note of "Sharing an AMI with Specific Users":

[aws.amazon.com/articles/530](http://aws.amazon.com/articles/530)

You can create an AMI through the AWS GUI by selecting your source instance, clicking the "Instance Actions" dropdown and clicking "Create Image".

Comment: how do I find out target user's AWS ID?

Comment: Go into their account page and grab their AWS account number.  account number = AWS ID.

Comment: Link is dead. Maybe this one has the same info: http://aws.amazon.com/articles/530